# Grub doesn't recognises already plugged in USB keyboard

Tags: grub2, grub4dos

I am not able to use my USB keyboard in Grub screen of my laptop. It works in BIOS, Windows and lubuntu.

---

What I've tried:

1. changing everything that I could find related to USB in BIOS.
2. adding GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="usb usb_keyboard ehci ohci uhci"
   GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="usb_keyboard" to /etc/default/grub. and ran grub-mkconfig.

---

What works:

1. Using my laptop keyboard instead of USB keyboard.
2. disconnecting and reconnecting the USB keyboard when I'm on Grub screen every time.

---

Grub version: 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.28

Answer (score 0):

Access BIOS Setup and go to Integrated Peripherals and then enable Legacy USB Support, reboot and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: This is enabled by default. tried turning it off, it has no effect on the issue.